# ASP.NET MVC does not deserialize JSON correctly when Conten-Type is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC 4, I have a controller that accepts a JSON structure:

```
public class SomeDto {
    ...
    public Boolean IsUnicornAlive { get; set; }
    ...
}

[HttpPost]      
public ActionResult DoSomething(SomeDto dto) {
...
}
```

Now if this POST request comes in **without** Content-Type specified:

```
{
...
"IsUnicornAlive":true
...
}
```

the action still gets called but IsUnicornAlive property would be false. Essentially this is a problem on the side that created the request, but still I would expect ASP to not treat it silently and not call my action with defaulted values. The most appropriate handling in this case would be a 4xx error, 415 ideally. What would be the easiest way to implement it? Or is there a way to know that default values were used inside the controller action?

Note: this question is not about ASP.NET WebApi which does not have this issue. This is specifically about MVC.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a custom ModelBinder for SomeDTO and parsing the incoming data yourself and deciding whether to deduce the values, add a modelstate error, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ModelState property of the Controller. For example ModelState.Keys.Count == 0 when the default value was used but you might find something even nicer in that object.